# Ruby on rails. Ajax, jquery affecting all of same class in partial

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, this, partials

I am a complete novice with jquery, but I am trying to add ajax stuff to my rails app. I am rendering a partial, which shows a list of users and a link to rate each user next to them. When I click the link the form successfully renders and submits etc. etc. but the problem I have is that the form renders on every instance of the class.
I have searched and tried using `$(this)` but that seems to break everything (nothing renders).

Link that is rendered multiple times in the partial:

```
<td> <%= link_to 'Click here to rate this user', new_user_review_path(:user_id => request.gig.user.id, :gigid => request.gig.id), class: "new-review", remote: true %> </td>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.new-review').hide().after('<%= j render("form") %>')
```

(all instances of .new-review hide and the form gets displayed for every user)

I have tried various things by searching (none of which have worked);

```
$(this).find('.new-review').hide().after('<%= j render("form") %>')

$(this)('.new-review').hide().after('<%= j render("form") %>')

$(".new-review").click(function(){
    $(this).find('.new-review').hide().after('<%= j render("form") %>');
});

$('.new-review', this).hide().after('<%= j render("form") %>')
```

Any hints would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood the problem is that all links have a class '.new-review', so jQuery, instead of using the one you need, uses them all. Somehow you need to sepereate the links. I would suggest chaning a class using this:

```
#{@user.id}
```

in your case it would be something like this:

```
<td> <%= link_to 'Click here to rate this user', new_user_review_path(:user_id => request.gig.user.id, :gigid => request.gig.id), class: "new-review-#{@user.id}", remote: true %> </td>
```

and for jQuery you would need to change it like this:

```
$('.new-review-<%= @user.id %>').hide().after('<%= j render("form") %>')
```

Not sure if I understood the question right but I hope this helps or gives any hints.

Comment: You understood the question perfectly! Thanks for the reply, so far I have successfully changed the class to include the user id, but the jquery is responding with a 500 internal error.

Comment: Did you try using "request.gig.user.id" instead of "@user.id" ?

Comment: I am using class: "new-review-#{request.user.id}" which correctly gives it a unique ID. Then I am using $('.new-review-<%= request.user.id %>') but this is throwing a 500 internal error.

Comment: It seems the jquery isn't working if there is a number in the class name. If I manually set the id's to eg. 20, and add $('.new-review20, it does not work.

Comment: This is essentially correct. I installed firebug and got a look at the jquery errors which I should be able to correct. The errors have nothing to do with the answer. Thanks for your help.